# Instagram not visible in useragent for newer iphone versions

Tags: iphone, safari, user-agent

I have an hypothesis that inapp-browsers such as Instagram's, Facebook's and TikTok's browsers arn't visible in the useragent for newer versions of Iphones or Safari. Does anyone have any idea if this could be the case and why?

Has Instagram in useragent:
UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/20G81 Instagram 315.1.2.21.112 (iPhone13,2; iOS 16_6_1; sv_SE; sv; scale=3.00; 1170x2532; 559614958)

Doesn't have Instagram in useragent:
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1